# getting categories with post count in category in entity framework

Tags: asp.net, linq, entity-framework

i have 2 tables called :

```
Categories
Posts
```

in category i save my categories like :

```
CategoryID CategoryTitle
1          HTML
2          CSS
```

and in posts i have data like this :

```
PostTitle  PostContent CategoryID
```

now i want to list my categories with post counts for each category
can you give me a query to do this?
i used this query :

```
var cats = (from c in contecxt.Categories select new {
   CategoryID,
   CategoryTitle
   Count = (from p in context.Posts where p.CategoryID == c.CategoryTitle).Count()
}).ToList();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using EF, and you have your foreign key relationships properly set up, then you should have a navigation property on your `Category` object that is a collection of `Post`. In which case, all you would need to do is the following, using LINQ's extension method syntax:

```
var cats = context.Categories.Select(cat => 
              new { cat.CategoryID, cat.CategoryTitle, PostCount = cat.Posts.Count() })
```

Comment: unfortunately i don't have relationship in tables :-(

Comment: Why don't you? It sure looks to me like you have a one to many with Category and Posts. You're sure you haven't at some point made a foreign key between them? You need one if you haven't.

Comment: You know i didnt use foreign key and i am using with query, but i created foreign key when you said and it works fine, thanks very much bro.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this -

```
var cats = ctx.Categories.GroupBy(item => item.CategoryTitle)
                        .Select(g => new
                        {
                            CategoryTitle = g.Key,
                            Count = g.Sum(x => x.Posts.Count())
                        }
                                      );
```

Comment: You don't need to use Sum() at all when you can call for the posts count.